# Make nginx redirect to HTTPS even with competing location regex

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have the following configuration inside a nginx `server {...}` block:

```
location /someapp { 
  if ( $https != "on" ) { 
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  } 

  location ~ \.php$ { 
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
  } 
}
```

The problem is:

- when I access `http://example.com/someapp/somefile.html` (or just `/someapp`), I'm am redirected to HTTPS,
- but when I access `http://example.com/someapp/somefile.php`, I am not redirected to HTTPS.

By the way, this is consistent with [the doc](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), that says:

> To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.

So when `location ~ \.php$` is a match, `location /someapp` is ignored, even if the request is for `.../someapp/somefile.php`.

Having the `location ~ \.php$ {...}` block outside of the parent `location /someapp {...}` block doesn't change this behaviour.

**How can I redirect every HTTP to HTTPS request to `/someapp` *without* having to duplicate the `if` and `return` lines into the php location block?**

Comment: Please add the complete nginx configuration to the question as shown by `nginx -T` command.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I cannot add so much information for confidentiality purposes. I added some nginx doc snippet however, which makes the nature of my problem more clear I hope.

Comment: totor, have you maybe thought about replacing the real domain or ips with example.com?

Comment: Without the larger context it is not possible to propose a good solution to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Suggestion would be

```
server {
       
        server_name example.com *.example.com;
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

this would create a basic server for port 80 and tell the browser to permanently use 443